# how do I resize the width of Summernote?

Tags: summernote

So I've loaded Summernote to my webpage, but it doesn't fit right, as you can see below.
The red border is my column, but as you can see there is empty space on the right. 
How do I adjust the width? I'm using Django by the way.

[image]

Comment: just modify the CSS to make it fit in your containing element

Comment: Well, I've installed django-summernote with pip, and can't find any folder of it.

Answer (score 0):

I just had this problem and you can change the size via settings, just add to your settings.py :

```
SUMMERNOTE_CONFIG = {
    # You can put custom Summernote settings
    'summernote': {
        # Change editor size
        'width': '100%',
    },
}
```

Documentation available in:
https://github.com/summernote/django-summernote